# How to convert between predicate types in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I want to convert `Expression<Func<DTOItem, bool>> predicate` to `Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate` with entity framework where `DTOItem` is mapped class of entity and `Item`(a table in database) is entityframe work class.

```
   IDTOItemRepository itemRepo = new DTOItemRepository();
   DTOItem itemObject = itemRepo.Single(q => q.ItemID == 1 && q.ItemType == 1);
```

where `q => q.ItemID == 1 && q.ItemType == 1` is of type `Expression<Func<DTOItem, bool>>`. 
Now i need to convert this expression to `Expression<Func<Item, bool>>`

Comment: it will be more approviate if we discuss the issue rather then anything else

Comment: They are discussing the issue.  Their point is that the way that you've written your question doesnt give us enough information to answer it, it only shows that you want a free answer.  Please post the code that you've tried so far as to give us better context for the question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit and improve your question, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) and it's [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) portion, it will do exactly that for you (but not in a direct way). What it does is let you turn a `IQueryable<Item>` to a `IQueyable<DtoItem>` so you could use your `Expression<Func<DTOItem, bool>>` on it, then when you go to perform the query aginst the backing store AutoMapper will transform the `Expression<Func<DTOItem, bool>>` portion in to a `Expression<Func<Item, bool>>` portion to be passed on to the EF provider.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //This needs to be done once when your program starts up.
     //You may need to do a more complicated "CreateMap" depending on how Item and DTOItem relate.
     Mapper.CreateMap<Item, DTOItem>();

     RunMyProgram();
}

public DTOItem GetItem()
{

     using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext())
     {
         IQueryable<Item> itemQuery = context.Items;
         return itemQuery.Project().To<DTOItem>()
                         .Single(q => q.ItemID == 1 && q.ItemType == 1);
     }

     //the above translates to the equivalent code
     /*         
     return itemQuery.Where(q => q.itemid == 1 && q.itemtype == 1)
                     .Select(a => new ItemDTO {ItemID = a.itemid, ItemType = a.itemType, SomeType = a.sometype} )
                     .Single();
     */
}

public class DTOItem
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public String SomeType {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public int itemid { get; set; }
    public string itemtype { get; set; }
    public String sometype {get; set;}
}

public class MyDatabaseContext: DbContext 
{
    public MyDatabaseContext(): base()
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This way it it will get all record from database and the apply the filter right?

Comment: No it will not get all the records, it will apply the filter first then only get the filtered records from the database (which is what you ***want*** to happen). do `((ObjectQuery)itemQuery).ToTraceString()` to see the SQL it would generate.

Comment: That is from your entity framework context. I have updated my answer again to help elaborate.

Comment: now getting this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Well then you did something wrong. You have a function pointing at itself, (I have also seen it from non thread safe collections used from multiple threads). Debug it, and if you can't figure it out ask a new question with the relevant code included.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You can do the opposite easily enough.

Let's take a look at another example.

I promise that if you give me an apple, I can tell you if it's still fresh.  I know everything there is to know about every single kind of apple.

How can you use my knowledge to determine if any given piece of fruit is still fresh?  You can't.  I know about apples, but I don't know about other types of fruit.  I can't make the guarantee that if you give me any kind of fruit I'll know if its fresh or not.

Now what if you were asked to determine if any type of Red Delicious apple is fresh?  Can you use the information I can give you to provide an answer to that question *in all cases*?  Sure you can.  I can handle any kind of apple, limiting your questions to just one kind is no problem for me.

You have a function that knows how to take any DTOItem and return a boolean.  You can't use that to take an Item at all and return a boolean, because what if that item isn't a DTOItem?  Then what will you do?  But if you have a method that can take any item at all and return a boolean then by all means you can "pretend" that it only accepts DTOItems.  It can handle any item, limiting it's input to just DTOItems isn't a problem.